# Are questions with different symptom(s), same cause, same solution duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Users often ask questions about *symptom(s)*, as opposed to causes, since askers often haven't discovered the cause of the symptom(s) they're experiencing at the time of asking. Are questions with the **same *cause*** and the **same *solution***, but **different *symptoms*** duplicates?

##### Example

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156175/activerecordstatementinvalid-pgundefinedcolumn-error-column-does-not-exis) attempts to solve the error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column does not exist)

The root cause of this error can also cause many other different errors, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253713/camelcase-column-in-postgresql-database-in-rails-activerecord):

> undefined method ''

Although it has the same cause, and the same solution, it exhibits a different set of symptoms.

Comment: [_"The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer..."_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, that's actually perfect. Basically if the solution's the same, then it should be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Essentially, @stevec, yes. Different questions can still have the same solution, and so an existing different question, with the same answer, can still be a duplicate candidate. If the new question is good though you can still up vote it, if you wish. This means that the post won't be deleted (by the roomba) and so can act as a "signpost" for future users with the same question.

Comment: Note that @jonrsharpe quote should be evaluated in context of the last sentence: "There are many ways to ask the same question, and a user might **not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way**". The objective of closing as duplicates isn't that all answers are in the same place, but all answers _to the same question_ are.

Answer (score 2):

If someone has a different symptom they can't find the duplicate.

So they did nothing wrong and did their best.

But the expert should close it as duplicate and think about creating a canonical question with all symptoms and one or more solutions to the problem.

Comment: +1 I think *the expert should close it as duplicate and think about creating a canonical question with all symptoms and one or more solutions to the problem* seems sensible. Although if it's not appropriate for some reason to amalgamate all the symptoms into one question, I think upvoting the duplicate is sensible to ensure it remains a [signpost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/are-questions-with-different-symptoms-same-cause-same-solution-duplicates/411597#comment868258_411592) toward the canonical is good too.